# Bootstrap and Zeplin.IO

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, zeplin

I'm not familiar with Zeplin IO but UX person is creating mockups in that application and then I will need to use Bootstrap to develop site based on exported HTML/CSS from Zeplin.

My question is if UX person can import Bootstrap CSS to Zeplin to have starting point of what will be used for development?

Comment: I'm not aware of anything available at the moment. This is discussed in this Quora thread: https://www.quora.com/Is-Bootstrap-redundant-when-using-the-Sketch-Zeplin-Invision-toolchain

Answer (score 1):

Normally Designers are using Sketch, Photoshop or Adobe XD to do the design and they export it to Zeplin. Actually there is noway to create mockups with zeplin.

Zeplin automatically generates accurate specs, assets and code snippets from designs, that helps for UI Development. Still there is no way to generate bootstrap codes. but you can get the CSS or SASS properties very easily.